Avoiding the 'Great Wall of Textus'
Atop a great question about style and formatting from some of the original users on the site and another about Bible citation here, we have the issue about writing questions or answers that are:

Lengthy
Unclear

New users may try their best to provide thorough explanations in questions and answers for how students might be expected in higher education. After or during college or grad school, a user asks a question on our site, but the writing style we look for is very different. This difference is not easy to understand or explain.
Brevity, but how?
We don't want answers that are too long, or questions for that matter.
How can a user think of writing style so as to keep a post "short enough"? How is the academic style of a research journal different from the style used on our site?

See If I Had More Time, I Would Have Written a Shorter Letter – Quote Investigator® for a list of quotations on this topic.  E.g. asked how long it takes to prepare a speech, Woodrow Wilson replied: "That depends on the length of the speech. IIf it is a ten-minute speech it takes me all of two weeks to prepare it; if it is a half-hour speech it takes me a week; if I can talk as long as I want to it requires no preparation at all. I am ready now.". Many new users (and a few old ones) seem to be in the third category.

@RayButterworth That could be a bona fide answer.

THEFORMATOFTHEHOLYSAINTSWASBESTWHOMADETHELETTERINGTHEIRBEAUTY•BEAUTIFULLETTERINGBYEQUALSCRIBES•TOBETHEWORLDSLIGHTTHEYLETTEREDTHELORDSWORDSLIKELIGHTTHATFLOWEDTOEVERYEDGEOFEVERYPAGE•SOBEWAREOFFORMATTERSANDPAGINATORSWHOJUSTIFYTHEIRWORDSWITHTOOLBARBUTTONSANDNOTBYTHEHOLYSAINTSIAMSMILING

IFWEWANTTOGOBACKTOTHEOLDWAYS•LETSREALLYGOBACKBACKTOTHEOLDOLDWAYS

Newswriting: Less is more
This is not an expected standard on the site, but it can serve as a "North Star" to point one's writing in a good direction.
Contrast the Science-Journal/academic English writing wtih Newswriting English. In school, professors and teachers rarely address this issue. They teach students to write "the correct" way, instead of "writing the academic way, not the pithy way".
Let's take a quote from a new user (smart, respected, educated, good English, insightful ideas, but academic style, thus some thought this was 'too long') which led to the "wall of text" objection from our reviewers:

I argued that there are several functional literary clues that indicate Luke’s apologetic purpose.

...great for school, but those 14 words could be just 5...

Several clues tell Luke's purpose.

Here's what an editor might be thinking...

I argue that - of course you do or this wouldn't be here.
there are - indeed.
functional - they probably aren't broken or Luke wouldn't use them.
literacy - they probably won't be mathematical on a hermeneutics site.
that - dependent clause pronoun handle not needed because we moved the object to subject when re-writing the sentence to use active instead of  passive voice. (Avoid passives; they add words.)
indicate - same as tell when being brief.
apologetic - most likely since it wouldn't be comical, poetic, or tragic.

There is nothing wrong with using any of these words, except in this sentence they don't add meaning. In other sentences, using the word apologetic could be vital to make the point.
That is merely one small example. If you read a book like the Associated Press Guide to News Writing, you will see many examples that shorten longer sentences in news articles with explanations just like this. (Yes, I have a copy on my shelf.)
Newswriting is one way of cutting down the word count from a "Great Wall of Textus".

In explaining this Newswriting English alternative, though seemingly brutal for any and every "extra word", this is not meant as any insult. This is what editors must think in order to keep newspapers in business. It is a What can I do to be better? type of internal dialog. (Later, this user wrote a first answer that was amazingly impressive! The issue was not about quality or insight, only about the particular writing style we use here.)
I myself, when writing my own articles and blogs, think of my own words in this way to help me take an ax to my work. A vlogger I filmed for also would do the same thing, cutting out 98% of his favorite video footage, being brutal to all the things he liked about his own work, getting things down to the absolute minimum so that the rest of the world could see his work in the fleeting time the world has available.
Consider a similar perspective when writing for users and visitors on our site. We want our posts to be small enough to be visible.

"to help me take an ax to my work" — I used to write technical documentation, low-level computer programs, and longer personal essays. Regardless of which it was, I'd generally write as much as I could as quickly as I could to get the fundamental thoughts out of my head, then tidy it up, and then start simplifying and deleting. There wasn't an abrupt transition between the steps, but when, at the end of the day, I could say "I've got less now than I had yesterday", I would know I was almost finished. ¶　Today's people seldom edit their work, they just add more explanations.

We want our posts to be small enough to be visible - well-phrased

I'll admit I don't use it as often as I'd like, but I love the traditional newspaper article style for answers: the editor says "we have 7 inches available on page 9, takes your long article, cuts it (literally with scissors) off at the paragraph break near 7 inches, pastes it (literally with paste) into the empty spot, and then prints it like that, without changes. If your truncated article seems incomplete, or confusing, or pointless, you didn't write it correctly, you "buried the lede". The leading "nutgraph" should tell everything that needs to be told, everything else is added detail.

@RayButterworth Newswriting—a completely different side of the page.
